# PHP Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi everyone I am getting this error message:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/url.com/wp-content/plugins/WPEC-Personalize-3.8/wpec-personalization.php on line 228 and 326 and defined in /home/url.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990
```

I have found the code on line 228 and 326:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT enabled FROM ". $table_name ." WHERE pers_id  = ". $myresults->pers_id." AND product_id = ".$product_id));
```

And changed it to the new wordpress (3.5 query) standard:

```
$add = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT enabled FROM %s WHERE pers_id = %d AND product_id = %d",
    $table_name, 
    $myresults->pers_id, 
    $product_id
));
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong but when once i updated the code below i stopped getting the error message but every time i update the product it duplicates all the custom fields the plugin is creating.

See example: https://www.americasfinestmailbox.com/products-page/birds/hummingbird-vertical/

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the plugin author does not support this plugin any more.

I have pasted the whole code here: http://www.pastebin.com/gxqEjee2

Thanks! 
William

Comment: can you give us the line 900 of  /home/url.com/wp-includes/wp-db.php

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: /**
  * Escape data. Works on arrays.
  *
  * uses wpdb::_escape()
  * uses wpdb::_real_escape()
  * since  2.8.0
  * access private
  *
  * param  string|array $data
  * return string|array escaped
  */
 function _escape( $data ) {
  if ( is_array( $data ) ) {
   foreach ( (array) $data as $k => $v ) {
    if ( is_array($v) )
     $data[$k] = $this->_escape( $v );
    else
     $data[$k] = $this->_real_escape( $v );
   }
  } else {
   $data = $this->_real_escape( $data );
  }

  return $data;
 }

Answer (score 0):

your problem is a design problem.
You want to use prepared statement as you heard "this is good for security". But the problem is that you are using them as if they were not prepared statement.

When you use prepared statement you expect your program to work like this :

1. Send and parse a query without parameters value
2. Send parameters
3. Execute the query and got to 2 while you need the query whatever the parameters.

So you just can't give the parameters *inside* the query, you have to give placeholders which, in worldpress, start with a `%` . 
Then, in you `prepare` method you will give the values so that they will be securized and sent safly.

Comment: Do you think you could give me an example using my code? Im just not sure how to apply your steps. Thanks!

Comment: I can give you a piece of code but it would be a copy/past from the "new wordpress standard" query you gave.
Take my message as the explanation of how does this "standard" works and why you have to give those params.